# PTP for photo transfer not working on my S6 edge

Tags: photos, 5.1-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-s-6

I have a Mac (iMac, newest model with newest software) and it is impossible to access photos from camera roll of my S6 edge (128 GB) in USB PTP mode. 
In Apple Photo app it shows the device but it always says "no photos". I talked with Samsung support and they said that the only way to transfer photos is to make a full backup with Smart Switch (MTP mode). This transfers 30-40 GB of my photo data only for few new photos in a new backup folder on my Mac. So at the moment I transfer photos via Email or Dropbox - both are extremely slow and unpractical because of internet. 
I also tried another Mac and other cables. I tried a S4 as well which worked fine (just plug in cable and it automatically shows all photos). There is also an integrated file browser in Smart Switch which works but this is also not useful for photos. I also asked this question in a German Android forum and was not getting good solutions (e.g. "Airdroid" software) so far.
Since MTP works for me I guess this is a software and not a hardware problem? Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Android File Transfer](https://www.android.com/filetransfer/) to browse your device in MTP mode. All pictures are normally saved in Phone/Camera/DCIM/ or SDCARD/Camera/DCIM/, by date. You can drag and drop the files to your mac. It essentially works like a Finder window. This way only the files you choose are transferred and at MTP speeds instead of PTP.

As for PTP not working, I'm assuming you have PTP selected, and screen unlocked when you try to open iPhoto?

Comment: Android File Transfer does not work with S6. Yesterday PTP is selected and device will be shown in Apple Photo. I also tried old iPhoto but the same problem.

Comment: Are you sure? Did you try? Another option is blue tooth. Select the files on the s6 then share them via bluetooth.

Comment: Yes I am sure. I am always getting a "Could not connect to device" with Android file transfer while Smart Switch has no problems. Bluetooth is strange indeed: I already had a long phone call with Apple support about this and Bluetooth connection between my S6 and iMac does not work.

Comment: @ImperatorMaximus with bluetooth, are you attempting to browse from the mac to the s6? Or are you sending from the s6 to the mac?

Comment: ok I got Bluetooth to work now. It was my fault I thought I need a connection before but it connects only by sending. I tried to send a 30MB video file but it says 10 minutes and I aborted it after 4 minutes. So I will definitely not use this again. I want PTP over USB cable or similar and this should be available in my opinion. It is like having a camera without being able to get the photos on PC. Is there any other Samsung forum or better support service email where I can ask for help? Apple has got discussions.apple.com. Does any similar exists from Samsung?